# como agregar datos de una tabla en cajas de texto usando un select2

Tags: php, select2, textbox

Tengo una lista desplegable en Html que muestra los datos de un campo de la base de datos y lo que quiero cuando el usuario seleccione un valor de la lista desplegable, me muestre los demás campos en cajas de texto.

for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
?>

">  


 SELECCIONA

SELECCIONA NUMERO DE PART

```
\<br\>
\<div class="mb-4"\>
\<div class="form-control-lg"\>
\<select id="select_etiqueta" name="select_etiqueta" onchange='this.form.submit()'class="js-example-basic-single form-control"\>
\<option value="0"\> SELECCIONA \</option\>
\<?php
for ($i=0; $i \< count($data); $i++)
{
?\>

\<option value="\<?php echo $data\[$i\]\['num_parte'\]?\>"\> \<?php echo $data\[$i\]\['num_parte'\] ?\> \</option\>

                                             <?php } 
                                            ?>
                                          </select>
                                      </label>
                                          </section> 
                                   </div>

\<input type="textbox" name="nom_cliente_parte"\>\<br\>  
\<div class="row mb-3"\>  
div class="col-md-6"\>
\<label class="form-label"\>NUMERO DE PARTE \</label\>
\<input type="textbox" class="form-control" name="select_input" id="" value="\<?php echo $\_POST\['select_etiqueta'\]?\>"\>

\</div\>
\<div class="mb-3"\>
\<label class="form-label"\>DESCRIPCION\</label\>
\<input type="text" class="form-control" name="select_input" id="" value="\<?php echo $\_POST\['select_etiqueta'\]?\>"\>
\</div\>
```

Comment: Para lograrlo debes hacer peticiones asíncronas a través de `ajax` o `fetch`. Investiga un poco al respecto y regresa si tienes dudas mas puntuales.